# Tag for questions about superseded theories

Tags: discussion, tags

I've got a number of questions about theories that were once believed, but have since been made obsolete by new discoveries.  Topics such as:

- the theory that [rain follows the plow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_follows_the_plow)
- the belief that the earth was [flat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Earth)
- theories about the [inhabitants of the antipodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichthones)
- the [phlostigon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlogiston_theory) theory of combustion
- the idea that there might be a [world in the moon](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14315/a-world-in-the-moon) (a question I asked earlier)

I think these should all have a tag in common, something like *antiquated-theory* or *old-beliefs*, but I'm not sure what to call such a tag.

I've been holding off asking some of these questions until I figure out how to tag them.

**What should this tag be called?**

Comment: Why is the existing [tag:science] tag not sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

There is a "[history of ideas](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-ideas)" tag, and I agree with T.E.D. that the "science" tag would be sufficient for those questions.

I don't think that the science and history of ideas tag should be merged, because there could be questions about the history behind non-scientific ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not actually aiming to reopen the theories in question, but ask about how these theories developed, were adopted and then debunked, what you're going for is asking questions about the [*history of ideas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_ideas) or [*intellectual history*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_history). I think tagging them as such would be enough - I don't think having a more specific tag about *failed* ideas is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

History and Philosophy of Science
or
History of Science

are the discipline terms for this work